# White Noise Generator Through Low Pass Filter - Autocorrelation of normalized data dropping below 0 (showing negative correlation)

Tags: data-analysis, signal-processing, noise

I am doing the following experiment:
http://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/a/ab/Correlation.pdf

It is basically a white noise generator running through a low pass filter.  Sample voltages are taken and normalized, then autocorrelated using a few methods.   The autocorrelation using normalized data is supposed to start at a value of 1 at 0 lag (which it does) and then exponentially decay to 0(which it doesnt).  However it is decaying below 0.

Also The auto generated coefficient for an exponential fit (a*np.exp(-(t/b)) + c) (b should = RC), does not match the RC constant of the Low pass filter (R=10kohm, C=0.5 microF, RC=5ms).

The methods I am using for the autocorrelation are as follows:
f=list of voltage values with mean subtracted from each value, 100,000 samples @ 10000 S/s

Using Built  in Correlate function:

```
def autocorr(f):

    result = np.correlate(f, f, mode='full')

    return result[result.size/2:]

autocorr=autocorr(f)

autocorr /= autocorr[autocorr.argmax()]
```

[image]

Using FastFourierTransform:

```
N = len(f)

fvi = np.fft.fft(f) #n=2*N)

acf = np.real( np.fft.ifft( fvi * np.conjugate(fvi) )[:N] )
```

[image]

Plotting using inbuilt python autocor plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.acorr(f)
```

[image]

Which you can see does not drop below 0.  I cannot find out the exact code that is executed with the plt.acorr(f) as it does not support outputting of data.

Here is the fitted exponential (clearly showing dip below 0) 
fitting function =

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(t,a,b,c):

return a*np.exp(-(t/b)) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t, acf)
```

[image]

However the autogenerated constant from the exponential fit, that should equal RC (5ms)  actually comes out as 1.043822ms
Also when I reduce the RC by 50% the calculated coefficient reduces by 33%.  Also if I change the sampling frequency this reduces the coefficient

Is there a way to produce the autocorrelation of the data gathered, that consists of an exponential decay to 0 with the decay constant as the RC of the low pass filter circuit?

I have tried various RC values for the LPF, they all dip below 0, in fact the lower the RC, the lower it dips below 0.

Could this be related to an incorrect offset voltage of the white noise generator?  I changed the offset, and it did increase the lowest value that the autocorrelation drops to, but I am not sure if I adjust it again it will fix the problem completely.

So to recap, 2 issues

- Autocorrelation does not decay to 0, it drops below 0
- Fitted exponential curve decay coefficient, does not equal the RC constant of the circuit.

This thread [Autocorrelation of noise - negative correlation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106440/autocorrelation-of-noise-negative-correlation)  Seems to be related to the same experiment and the same issue (unanswered)

```
                      **UPDATE 7-3-15:**
```

Things that have been tried:
The White Noise generator has a threshold knob to  set the threshold frequency.  It did not fix either of the issues:
Highest Threshold Setting:
[image: Highest threshold setting]

Lowest Threshold Setting:

[image: Lowest Threshold Setting]

Autocorrelation was fitted to Python generated White noise filtered through simulated RC low pass filter circuits (different RC values).  This produced correct results.  This would lead me to believe the code being used to autocorrelate is correct.

I have tested the FFT method and inbuilt python correlate function to autocorrelate data and they give the same results, also confirming the code should be ok.

A physical signal generator, generating square waves was tested through the A2D and plotted v/s time.  The result was correct with the correct timings matching the sampling frequency.  This confirms the A2D is functioning correctly.

Example of square wave through A2D:

[image]

The square waves were also ran through 2 RC low pass filter circuits.  The correct RC values were calculated using an exponential fit.  This confirms the RC circuits are functioning correctly and also the code used to fit the exponentials is functioning.
However decay below 0 occurred

Example of fitted exponential on filtered square wave:

[image]

There is a voltage offset in the white noise generator, this was adjusted a few times (above and below 0V), it did not fix the incorrect fitted exponential RC constants.  It does effect the decay of the autocorrelated data, but not to the point where it can be determined if this is the cause of the issue.

Plot below.  B=before 1st offset change, A = after 1st offset change, A2-x = after 2nd offset change.  RC's correspond to eachother e.g. B1, A1, A2-1 have the same RC etc

[image]

I have checked the power spectra of 2 samples of non filtered noise from the white noise generator with the following results:

Please ignore the units

[image]

[image]

It is possible the noise being generated isn't white noise at all.  I will need to check with more samples.

The data does fit autocorrelated white noise (decaying exponential), the problem is, it decays beyond 0 and then recovers and the decay constants are roughly a factor of 10 out from the actual RC values of the low pass filters that the white noise is being filtered through.
Currently testing the power spectra of the white noise (not filtered or normalized).All plots of data are just samples with a few samples, I have ran more, to many to include.
Thanks to User:Floris for suggestions on what to look at.

```
                      **UPDATE 7-15-15:**
```

Well it turns out the problem does lie with the white noise generator.  A very strange issue.

I added a voltage follwer circuit before the RC circuit (to increase the current available) and the results improved dramatically.  I'm not sure if this is the final fix as there is some weird issues with the voltage follower, adding voltage gain for some reason.  I tested with another white noise source before using the voltage follower and I was able to achieve ~ 90% accuracy comparing the exponentially fit RC value to the theoretical RC value and can now match that with the original white noise generator and voltage follower circuit.

Example of a collection of 10 sample sets @ RC=5ms:
[image]

Compared to the "working" white noise source:
[image]

I will update with a final answer when I know exactly whats happening and why the issue was occuring.  If anyone has any suggestions also, much appriciated.

Comment: I would recommend that you start by generating some _synthetic_ white noise to convince yourself that your signal processing is correct. If it is, then the fact that you see a negative correlation it suggests some "non white" structure in your signal. This _may_ be real... Incidentally - very well written question.

Comment: Im sorry if this seems stupid, but how would I generate synthetic white noise?

Comment: Also would this explain the wrong decay constant being generated with the exponential fit?

Comment: White noise generation - see http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/what-is-the-phase-and-magnitude-response-of-white-noise for an example and discussion

Comment: For curve fitting, I would use a straight line fit to the log of the data - and give less weight to the later points (which have more noise). Of course, since the data goes negative you already know a fit will be troublesome "out there". Note also that R and C values are typically inaccurate. It may be that the actual decay constant is accurate, and your components are not.

Comment: One more comment - in the line `autocorr=autocorr(f)` you overwrite your definition of the function. You really want to use different names for variables and functions...

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I will look into the noise generation and fitting straight line to the log of the data.  Why would the R and C component values not be accurate, I know they would have a small uncertainty, but not as much as the difference between the decay constant generated and the theoretical RC of 5ms?

Comment: Thanks for the info on overwriting the definition of the function,  Im actually new to python, (coming from matlab), so I am trying to get used to the syntax etc

Comment: I can see that... but the same thing would happen in matlab as well (it might warn you, but you would end up overwriting the definition in either environment). Capacitors are notoriously inaccurate unless you buy a high precision one. Look at the marking on the capacitor and check against [this chart](http://www.electronicsteacher.com/capacitor-chart.php)

Comment: Im using 2x electrolytic capacitors (2x 1 microF in series to give 0.5 microF).  When you say a straight line fit to the log of the data, do you mean the log of the autocorrelation data or the raw data?

Comment: Electrolytic is highly inaccurate. I mean straight line to log(autocorr). You have to stay away from the negative points (in fact you may have to accumulate your data at higher correlation length into fewer bins to ensure the points are positive).

Comment: Also, when working with frequencies, you have to be careful about factors of $2\pi$... not sure if that plays here but your factor 5 (and the uncertainty in capacitors) might be 6.283...

Answer (score 5):

A single measurement like this has a lot of noise on it - and random signal is always going to have some random correlation. You should definitely not pay too much attention to the stuff that is in the tail of the correlation distribution - it's all noise.

The fact that the built in function does not produce negative values is related to you only looking at the first 10 bins (which is the default). If you plotted the full range, it would go negative just like the others - use

```
plt.acorr(f, maxlags=None)
```

Incidentally, it does return all the values in four variables - if you do

```
result = plt.acorr(f, maxlags=None)
```

you can examine `result[0]` and `result[1]` to give you the values the function calculated - you will find it's similar (identical) to the one you get using other functions. The reason the plot is different, as I said, is that you are not looking at the same range of lags.

Let me demonstrate a few principles. I will be generating some white noise, filtering it with the response of an RC circuit, and plotting the autocorrelation multiple times. We are going to learn how to create white noise (and how to filter it); that the autocorrelation will not be the same twice; that it can go negative, even if you take the mean of 20; and that the measured time constant will vary by quite a bit. Bottom line - you will come away with a better feeling for this. There is much more to learn...

Here is the code:

```
# white noise

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy import stats

def autocorr(f):
    temp = np.correlate(f, f, mode='full')
    mid = temp.size/2
    return temp[mid:]

plt.close('all')

# simulate a simple RC circuit
# V = 1/jwC/(R+1/jwC) = 1/(jwRC+1)
C = 1e-6      # 1 uF
R = 1.0e3     # 1 kOhm
RC = R*C
fs = 100000   # sampling frequency
fc = 1.0 / RC # cutoff frequency
repeats = 100 # number of times experiment is repeated
ns = 10000    # number of samples per repeat (1/10th of a second)
nplot = 500   # number of samples in autocorrelation to plot

t = np.arange(ns)/(1.0*fs) # time corresponding to each sample
fr = fs / (2.0 * ns) # resolution per bin in the FFT

freq =  np.arange(ns) * fr  # frequency bins in FFT
response = np.divide(1, 1j * 2 * math.pi * freq * RC + 1) # complex response per bin

# plot response function:

fn = 4* np.floor(fc / freq[1]) # two octaves above 3dB point
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(freq[:fn], np.abs(response[:fn]))
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.title('Filter response: amplitude')

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(freq[:fn], np.angle(response[:fn], deg=1))
plt.title('Filter response: phase')
plt.ylabel('angle (deg)')
plt.xlabel('frequency')

fa = []  # array where we will store the filtered results
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
for j in range(repeats):
    e = np.random.normal(size=ns)
    # take Fourier transform:
    ff = np.fft.fft(e)
    # roll off the frequencies
    fr = ff * response
    # take inverse FFT:
    filtered = np.fft.ifft(fr)
    ac = autocorr(filtered)
    acNorm = np.abs(ac / ac.max()) # <<< using abs function here: get amplitude
    fa.append(acNorm)
    plt.plot(acNorm[:nplot])

plt.xlabel('correlation distance')
plt.title('Autocorrelation: result of %d samples'%repeats) 
plt.show()

# calculate the mean of the repeated samples:
repeatedMean = np.mean(fa, axis=0)

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.semilogy(repeatedMean[:nplot])
plt.title('mean of %d repeats'%repeats)
plt.xlabel('correlation distance')
plt.show()

# fit an exponential to the data
# anything beyond the first 20 points does not make much sense - contains no useful information

# fit an exponential to the data
# anything beyond the first 20 points does not make much sense - contains no useful information

nfit = fs*RC  # <<<< added
slopes = []
plt.figure()
for j in range(repeats):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t[:nfit], np.log(fa[j][:nfit]))
    plt.plot(t[:nfit], fa[j][:nfit])
    slopes.append(slope)
plt.title('autocorrelation used for fitting') # <<< fixed typo
plt.xlabel('correlation time')
plt.show()
print 'mean time constant is %.2f ms'%np.mean(np.divide(-1000,slopes)) # <<< changed
print 'standard deviation is %.3f ms'%np.std(np.divide(1000, slopes))  # <<< changed
```

And here are the plots it produces:

[image]

[image]

The time constant derived from these fits (inverse of slope) averaged over 100 fits was 1.01 ± 0.15 ms - consistent with the time constant of 1.0 ms that was implied in the choice of components in my code (1 kOhm and 1 uF).

Play around with the code - and let me know if this clears things up for you.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer.  I will be going through this today.

Comment: Can I ask, is the code you are using for applying the low pass filter just: 1-Apply Fourier Transform to noise data to take it into frequency domain? 2- Remove the frequencies required (using your previously defined "response" variable.  then 3- Apply inverse Fourier Transform to take the signal back to the time domain?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am doing. There are all kinds of other filter functions built in (Butterworth etc) which are "better" filters but which don't mimic the "imperfect" RC response as well (those might exist and I don't know about them...).

Comment: Is there a way to stop acNorm from containing complex values?  Or is it OK to just remove  the complex values and convert to a float?  When I try to use the code with an RC of 5ms, the fitted exponential  comes out with a slope of -170.007839ms

Comment: The absolute value (amplitude) of a complex number is calculated as the square root of the number multiplied by its complex conjugate, and is the correct value to use. The `abs` function does this for you: `abs(1+1j)=1.41...`.

Comment: As for getting the wrong time constant. This has to do with the fitting range which I had fixed at 100 points. I now adjusted it (see updated code) to be "one time constant worth of points". I also changed the calculation of the mean - instead of taking the mean of the slopes, then using the reciprocal to get the time constant, I take the reciprocal of the slopes. This will give a slightly different answer. Bottom line - with these tweaks I got 5.2 ±1.7 ms on my first attempt. These values do vary from run to run...

Comment: Thats great.  I ran a test by generating whitenoise and passing through the low pass code you gave, with the exact same values as my physical noise generator data, N=100,000, f=10,000, R=10kohm, C=0.5microF and using the code I had for plotting and it does give exactly the same shape plots.

Comment: However I am wondering why, when I just plot say the first 30ms of the data, the autocorrelation data dips below 0 very fast compared to your "autocorrelation used for fitting" plot, which doesnt seem to drop below zero as fast.

Comment: I reran with your changes and I get ~5ms also and ~6.5ms on my own exponential fit with the generated white noise through LPF code, which is right.  So it seems there may be a problem with my original noise data (from the physical noise generator), no matter how I try to fit an exponential, it does not come close at all to the 5ms RC constant.

Comment: As I said - it is quite likely that your capacitors are not even close to the value stamped on them... If you feed a square wave into the RC network and put a scope on the output, what kind of exponential wave do you get? Or if you put in a `sin` wave, at what frequency is the amplitude down by $\sqrt{2}$? This allows you to estimate the actual value of the capacitance. The answer may surprise you.

Comment: I tried a different Low pass RC filter yesterday with a more accurate capacitor.  The exponential, fitted RC constant now consistently comes out a factor of ~10 below the actual constant every time (the old RC circuit was varying wildly).

Comment: Over what range of time do you fit the exponential? You don't want to be fitting to the noises not the acf...Are you sure you have the sampling rate right? If you measure 100 times, does the value converge to the right value, or something completely different?

Comment: Im not sure how to set a range when using scipy.optimize.curve_fit.   I have tried chopping the data, just taking the first 30ms, however it is worse.  For instance the new RC circuit has an RC of 3.96ms.  If I fit an exponential to the full autocorrelated data (N=100k, f=10k) I get an RC of ~0.4ms and the curve fits quite well. If I just fit the exponential to the first 30ms of autocorrelated data (by just chopping the other points out), the RC = ~0.1ms and the curve does not fit well at all.

Comment: Chopping the data is how I would limit the fit range. Note that you can use an optimal parameter `sigma`. If you set this equal to the square root of the expected value (Poisson noise) you will suppress the tail "just right". If you have a sampling rate of 10 kHz and your fit gives you 0.4 ms you must have just 2 or 3 "significant" points in the ACF (every point shifts by 0.1 ms). Note that in my code above I was using a sampling rate of 100kHz and 10k samples (1/10th of a second)...

Comment: I am using a sampling rate of 10kHz and 100k samples.  Chopping the data did not fix the RC constant issue.  I have tried adjusting the voltage offset in the noise generator, that did not fix the issue either.  The fitted RC constants are still  10-30% of the actual RC.  When you say set this to "square root of the expected value (Poisson noise)", do you mean the square root of the mean of each sample? e.g (mean=np.ndarray.sum(f)/len(f)), then ==> sigma=sqrt(mean) <== adding this as a parameter to plt.plot ? or add it to scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Comment: I was thinking of adding the sigma value to the `curve_fit` routine. Your sampling rate may be too low to get a good fit. The signal correlation will decay too quickly.

Comment: Im just using the original experiment pdf linked in the 1st post.  They used a rate of 1 sample every 0.15ms.  I am at 0.1 ms per sample.  So it should be adequate. Though they do mention adding together the autocorrelations of 50 samples (just using the 1st 30ms of data of each).  I could not figure out how to do this correctly, as the plots came out very strange when I tried this.  I added together the first 30ms of autocorrelated data for each sample and arranged it in descending order.

Comment: In what way were the plots "strange" when you added them together? The sum of the autocorrelation functions for n samples should just be a smoother version of the same thing... And what do you mean by "arranged in descending order"?

Comment: They looked worse than the non-added data.  When you add the autocorrelation data together, (appending to one file), I then arranged the data in decsending order, so that it follows the original decay pattern.  I assumed thats what is meant by adding the autocorrelation data together, just appending all of the autocorrelated samples to one file.

Comment: I think you need to arrange your M autocorrelations for each of N experiments into an M x N matrix and average over M - so you end up with a single experiment with just N points. That is the average curve of my last plot above.

Comment: Ok I will look into that, not too sure about how to do that, the experiment documentation makes it sound much easier than having to go into matrices, it shouldnt be this tricky to get the data to pump out an RC constant that is close (within the same order of magnitude).  though the documentation just says "add the autocroelations together"

Comment: I use the word "matrix" (as a Matlab user) just as a 2D arrangement of experimental data. Take the 1st point of all the autocorrelations and average it. Repeat for the second, etc. That is what they (and I) mean.

Comment: The problem has been narrowed down a bit.  I used a square wave signal generator to test the A2D and RC circuits used and the code was tested, so it possibly looks like the white noise generator may be causing the problem (the code may still be a culprit, but it has been tested with the signal generator and python generated noise and worked fine).

Comment: How are you generating the white noise?

Comment: Using a white noise generator (purposely built, not by me, to generate white noise)

Comment: Is it a commercial device with known characteristics? What does its autocorrelation function look like without any (intentional) RC filtering? How about the Fourier Transform? If you ran 1000's of samples, calculated the power spectrum (FFT * complex conjugate of FFT) and then summed all those power spectra, you should end up with a flat (bumpy, but no structure) line. Do you?

Comment: I dont think it is a commercial box as such (no branding), but looks very professional.  I do not have the specs of it, just a circuit diagram.  The autocorrelation function (without filtering) matches that of white noise.  When normalized it has a value of 1 at 0 lag then fluctuates about 0 for lag>0.  Currently I am aquiring sample sets of N=100k at a frequency of 10k S/s.  Do you mean getting 1000's of these sets?  I have tried adding a few sets together and i get an autocorrelation equivalent to a single set

Comment: I have not tried adding a lot of the sets and analysed the power spectra.  But I take it you are suggesting to do this to confirm it is actually white noise, so that the power spectra should be equal??  I never thought of doing that, I'll try that today.  Does it matter if I use normalized data when finding the power spectrum?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use normalized data for this although I would use "raw". Multiple samples should show better if there are deviations from white noise. This is definitely a strange puzzle. When you have more data please update your question with all the details - and stripping out stuff that does not matter. It gets hard to follow these things otherwise.

Comment: update added to 1st post